# ¿De cuándo es la información que se muestra en las DMVs de SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito saber de cuando es la información que consulto en las DMVs, estoy haciendo un estudio de los triggers de mi entorno y necesito saber desde cuando cuentan las ejecuciones.

¿Desde cuándo cuentan las ejecuciones totales? Desde el arranque del motor no puede ser porque son muy pocas.

```
SELECT database_id,
        object_id,
        execution_count AS Exec_Cnt,
        total_worker_time AS Exec_Time,
        total_physical_reads AS Disk_Reads,
        total_logical_reads AS Mem_Reads,
        total_logical_writes AS Total_Writes,
        total_elapsed_time AS Total_Time, 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats 
    WHERE database_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,32767)
```

[image: trigger info]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3):

En la [documentación en linea](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-trigger-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), se lee:

> execution_count   bigint  The number of times that the trigger has been
> executed since it was last compiled.

Es decir, este número comienza desde la última compilación, que puede corresponder a:

- la última modificación del código del trigger
- cambios significativos en la cantidad de filas involucradas que terminen forzando la recompilación

Complementando la respuesta:

> cached_time   datetime    Time at which the trigger was added to the cache.

`cached_time` te informa la fecha/hora de la última compilación del trigger.

Comment: Agregando a la respuesta, la vista tiene una columna llamada `cached_time` que indica la fecha y hora de la última compilación.

Comment: @LuisCazares, buen dato, lo agrego a la respuesta, gracias